# C#: How to detect . in string and insert a space after it/How to insert space after n chars?

Tags: c#, string

Suppose I have a long string like `4600airportburlingame150anzablvd.burlingamecalifornia94010`. My code is breaking on this string. This is unusual, 99% of entries will not have a period. The CSS in the browser wraps if there are spaces in the string and there isn't any here.

1. How do I detect the period `(".")` and insert a space directly after it? Remember 99% of strings will not have a period in them. The code has to detect if it has a period and if so, do the insertion, otherwise not.
2. If I determine a maximum string length, how do I insert a space at some length?

Comment: Will your long strings ever have more than one period?  such as paragraphs of text?

Comment: Sir you asked a question, you get your answer in no time

Comment: Sir you've asked your question, you get your answer in no time, you probably saw it. Now, didn't you forget something?

Answer (score 9):

### ①

To insert a space after every dot:

```
var newString = oldString.Replace(".", ". ");
```

To insert a space after every dot except for the dots that *already have* a space or dots at the end of the string:

```
var newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, @"\.(?! |$)", ". ");
```

### ②

To insert a space after every *n* characters:

```
var newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, new string('.', n), m => m.Value + " ");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the regex solution, it works like a charm.

Comment: can anyone provide the javascript alternative for var newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, @"\.(?! |$)", ". ");

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Just edited my post. This will loop till there is no "." in your string. ıf there is none, it will skip it.

```
String myText = "4600airportburlingame150anzablvd.burlingamecalifornia94010";

while(myText.Contains("."))
{
    int indexOfDot = myText.IndexOf(".");
    myText = myText.SubString(0,indexOfDot) + " " + myText.SubString(indexOfDot + 1);
}
```

Comment: Who upvoted this wrong answer? The question clearly stated, “insert a space directly after it”, not “replace the dot with a space”.

Comment: @Timwi ~I'm pretty sure question was edited.. I always read the questions.

Answer (score 2):

Although a simple "String.Replace()" would work if you were only concerened with a single period, but what if you had multiple periods... or some already with a period space and others without... would you want to change ". " to ".  "?  Make this a function and pass a string to be "fixed"... this example uses multiple embedded periods with / without spaces after.  The result is a string where ONLY those periods without a following space will have one added to it.

```
String myText = "4600airpo. rtburl.ingame150.  anzablvd.burlinga.  mecalif.ornia94010"; 
int Dot = 1, LastDot = 0, DotSpace = 0;
while (Dot > 0)
{
   Dot = myText.Substring( LastDot ).IndexOf( "." );
   if (Dot > 0)
   {
      DotSpace = myText.Substring(LastDot).IndexOf(". ");
      if (Dot != DotSpace)
         myText = myText.Substring(0, LastDot + Dot +1) + " " 
                + myText.Substring(LastDot + Dot +1);

      LastDot += Dot +1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For 1, try `myStr = myStr.Replace(".", ". ");`. Do note that this assumes that a period will never be used in any other context (such as, for example, a decimal separator).

For 2, see Pabuc's answer.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's usually considered polite to leave a comment explaining why an answer is voted down along with a downvote.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `string.Replace(".", ". ")`

`String myText = "4600airportburlingame150anzablvd.burlingamecalifornia94010";

myText = myText.Replace(".", ". ");`

Comment: -1 - Read the question before answering it. Your code replaces the `.` with a space. This is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Not only that; `String.Replace()` does not do in-place replacements.

Comment: @Oded: I forgot the ". " in the replace method's second param!, thanks for the correction!